# Any good accompanying study material to go with JD Jackson Electrodynamics

Tags: resource-recommendations, classical-electrodynamics

I am doing self study with JD Jackson's "Classical Electrodynamics". Since not enrolled anywhere this is all I am using. At lot of places in the book, I feel need for more detail. At times its just the maths that I dont understand. I do try to look at maths books for understanding something but at times the exercise takes a lot of time. 
Is there any good video lecture/Notes/Slides to go with this book?

Comment: A potential duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/571571/149907

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you have already read an undergraduate text (like Griffiths). You can try [Modern Electrodynamics](https://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&field-keywords=zangwill&index=blended&link_code=qs&tag=wwwcanoniccom-20) by Andrew Zangwill.

Comment: Seconding this. Zangwill is a very conceptually deep exposition of Electrodynamics that doesn't get too bogged down in irrelevant technical details. I haven't read much of Jackson, but I hear it is just Electrodynamics + a bunch of integral gymnastics and math tricks.